# Solving a complex double-integral equation for a third variable

Tags: matlab, double, integral, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following equation for the variable h:
[image]

- F is the normal cumulative distribution function
- f is the probability density function of chi-square distribution.

**I want to solve it numerically using Matlab.**

First I tried to [solve the problem with a simpler version of function F and f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413238/solving-a-double-integral-equation-for-a-third-variable-in-matlab).

Then, I tried to solve the problem as below:

```
n = 3;    % n0 in the equation
k = 2;    
P = 0.99; % P* in the equation
F = @(x,y,h) normcdf(h./sqrt((n-1)*(1./x+1./y)));
g1 = @(y,h)integral(@(x) F(x,y,h).*chi2pdf(x,n),0,Inf, 'ArrayValued', true);
g2 = @(h) integral(@(y) (g1(y,h).^(k-1)).*chi2pdf(y,n),0,Inf)-P;
bsolve = fzero(g2,0)
```

I obtained an answer of 5.1496. The problem is that this answer seems wrong.

**There is a paper which provides a table of h values obtained by solving the above equation**. This paper was published in 1984, when the computer power was not good enough to solve the equation quickly. They solved it with various values:

- n0 = `3:20`, `30:10:50`
- k  = `2:10`
- P* = `0.9`, `0.95` and `0.99`

They provide the value of h in each case.

Now I'm trying to solve this equation and get the value of h with different values of n0, k and P* (for example n0=25, k=12 and P*=0.975), where the paper does not provide the value of h.

The Matlab code above gives me different values of h than the paper.
For example:

- n0=3, k=2 and P*=0.99: my code gives h = 5.1496, the paper gives h = 10.276.
- n0=10, k=4 and P*=0.9: my code gives h = 2.7262, the paper gives h = 2.912.

The author says

> The integrals were evaluated using 32 point Gauss-Laguerre numerical quadrature. This was accomplished by evaluating the inner integral at the appropriate 32 values of y which were available from the IBM subroutine QA32. The inner integral was also evaluated using 32 point Gauss-Laguerre numerical quadrature. Each of the 32 values of the inner integral was raised to the k-1 power and multiplied by the appropriate constant.

Matlab seems to use the same method of quadrature:

> q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax) numerically integrates function fun from xmin to xmax using global adaptive quadrature and default error tolerances.

---

Does any one have any idea which results are correct? Either I have made some mistake(s) in the code, or the paper could be wrong - possibly because the author used only 32 values in estimating the integrals?

Comment: You should provide a reference to the paper...

Comment: Wilcox, Rand R. "A table for Rinott’s selection procedure." Journal of Quality Technology 16.2 (1984): 97-100.

Comment: I have a copy of this paper, if any one is interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work, but the chi-squared distribution has (n-1) degrees of freedom, not n as in the code posted. If that's fixed then the Rinott's constant values agree with literature. Or at least, the literature that isn't behind a paywall. Can't speak to the 1984 Wilcox.